# Concurrent Data Store

Tags: java, database

What are alternatives are there for "concurrent data stores"?
That is I simply what to keep a set of values based on a key, and be able to read and write to those values through various applications.

At the moment, my intent is db4o, but I am producing a little more code than I would like in terms of creating classes, managing their access and getting data from them.

Can someone suggest alternatives based on their "experience" that I can review for myself?

PS. My aim, to minimize the amount of code I write, and the complexity in reading/writing.
I'm basically trying to have a similar "representation" of the REGISTRY (in-memory with persistence) in Windows across Unix platforms.

Comment: Have you looked at Hazelcast? It supports distributed concurrent collections, minimising code changes.

Comment: Thanks looks very interesting. Looks a bit heavy duty for what I am trying to do. I just need something really lightweight with minimal data transfer.